# Mot inconnu, ou syntaxe et sens non clairs (« lace », Aphorismes sur la sagesse dans la vie)

Tags: grammaire, sens, vocabulaire

> *Aphorismes sur la sagesse dans la vie*, Arthur Schopenhauer
> Traduit en français par J.-A. Cantacuzène
>
> Celui-là, au contraire, qui tient de ses parents une
> fortune suffisante pour vivre sera d'ordinaire
> récalcitrant; il est habitué à marcher *tête levée*; il n'a
> pas appris tous ces tours de souplesse; peut-être
> même s'avise-t-il de se prévaloir de certains talents
> qu'il possède et dont il devrait plutôt comprendre
> l'insuffisance en lace de ce qui se passe avec le
> *médiocre* et *rampant*;

Le mot « lace » ne se trouve pas dans les dictionnaires  sauf en tant que forme verbale du verbe « lacer »  ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/lace)) ; le verbe « lacer » est le mot le plus proche ; en supposant qu'il s'agisse de ce verbe il est toujours difficile d'analyser la phrase. S'agirait-il plutôt d'une erreur de typographie ? Le mot serait-il plutôt « face » ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`S'agirait-il d'une erreur de typographie ? Le mot serait-il plutôt « face » ?`
Oui, il faut bien lire "**face**".

I found [this translation](https://psychaanalyse.com/pdf/APHORISMES%20SUR%20LA%20SAGESSE%20DANS%20LA%20VIE%20%20-%20BIBLIO%20-%20ARTHUR%20SCHOPENHAUER%20(307%20PAGES%20-%2010,8%20Mo).pdf) *page 61* :

> Celui-là, au contraire, qui tient de ses parents une fortune
> suffisante pour vivre sera d'ordinaire récalcitrant; il est habitué à
> marcher tête levée; il n'a pas appris tous ces tours de souplesse;
> peut-être même s'avise-t-il de se prévaloir de certains talents qu'il
> possède et dont il devrait plutôt comprendre l'insuffisance en
> **face** de ce qui se passe avec le médiocre et rampant.

[Other translation](https://la-philosophie.com/lart-du-bonheur-selon-schopenhauer) :

> Contrairement à ceux qui sont contraints de mendier pour vivre, les
> autres qui tiennent de leurs parents une fortune suffisante sont
> habitués à marcher tête levée. Ils cherchent à se prévaloir de
> certains talents qu’ils possèdent d’autant plus qu’ils remarquent
> facilement l’infériorité de ceux qui occupent une position
> subordonnée.